# libstdc++.so.6 error on centos sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, centos6

I am using CentOS 6.8 and try to import sklearn. But I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DBSCAN.py", line 12, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install it by using yum.

```
sudo yum install libstdc++-4.4.7-18.el6.i686
[sudo] password for hangh: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: mirrors.vbi.vt.edu
 * base: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * elrepo: iad.mirror.rackspace.com
 * epel: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * updates: mirror.trouble-free.net
Package libstdc++-4.4.7-18.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
```

Comment: seems you're using linuxbrew, perhaps you should `brew install`?

Comment: [Shared by system ?](https://clients.cast-control.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=7)